# Working with multiple checkboxes in react with one OnChange not woking

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my project, I have many checkboxes I'm working on and the goal is to use one onChange to keep track of checked box and store their values inside an array and remove when uncheck. But what i have done is returning an error. Can someone please tell me with what I'm doing wrong. [codesandboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-zhukovsky-vo8h7?file=/src/App.js:0-1767)

the error i'm geeting

```
TypeError
selected.indexOf is not a function
OnChange
/src/App.js:11:24
   8 | 
   9 | const OnChange = (id)=>{
  10 |   let selected = isselected;
> 11 |   let find = selected.indexOf(id)
     |                      ^
  12 | 
  13 |   if(find > -1){
  14 |       selected.splice(find, 1)
```

Here is my code
App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {useState} from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [isselected, setisselected] = useState([])


  const OnChange = (id)=>{
    let selected = isselected;
    let find = selected.indexOf(id)

    if(find > -1){
        selected.splice(find, 1)
    }else {
        selected.push(id)
    }
    setisselected({selected})

    console.log(isselected)
}



  return (
    <div className="App">
                          <div className="first-search">
                          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            className="input-1"
                            value="Last 7 days"
                            name="last seven"
                            id= "1"
                            onChange={ (e)=>   OnChange(e.target.value)}
                            selected={ (e)=>  isselected.includes(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label htmlFor="">
                            Last 7 days
                          </label>
                        </div>



                        <div className="first-search">
                          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            className="input-1"
                            name="last24"
                            value="last24"
                            id= "2"
                            onChange={ (e)=>   OnChange(e.target.value)}
                            selected={ (e)=>  isselected.includes(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label htmlFor="">
                            Last 24 hours 
                          </label>
                        </div>

  </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: to see the checkbox is selected or not, you need to use `checked` attribute not `value`

Comment: And use `useEffect` or `useCallback` for detect the state is changed

Comment: please can you explain better @JamesGao

Answer (score 0):

setisselected({selected}) if this tries to reset *isselected* its been declared and is const !

note: name="last seven"
and
name="last24"
value="last24"
do not look good as personal coding convention.

*It would be good if you posted the error from a debug message from the browser. e.g. firefox or chrome.

Comment: I just added the error i'm getting @SamuelMarchant